# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `force_encoding' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, encoding, devise, actionview

I'm using Gems in 'vendor/bundler'. When I got Encoding error, I fixed it by adding a file named '`output_safty_encoding_patch.rb`'  in '`config/initializer`':

> output_safty_encoding_patch.rb

```
module ActiveSupport
  class SafeBuffer < String
    def concat(value)
      if value.html_safe?
        super(value.force_encoding('utf-8'))
      else
        super(ERB::Util.h(value.force_encoding('utf-8')))
      end
    end
    alias << concat
  end
end
```

Then I used gem 'devise' and tried to create a new post.
 I got this error.

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `force_encoding' for nil:NilClass):

My logs:

```
Processing by PostsController#new as HTML
  Rendered posts/_form.html.slim (30.2ms)
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (36.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 43ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `force_encoding' for nil:NilClass):
    1: = form_for(@post) do |f|
    2: -if @post.errors.any?
    3:   #error_explanation
    4:     h2= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") 
  config/initializers/output_safty_encoding_patch.rb:7:in `concat'
  app/views/posts/_form.html.slim:1:in _app_views_posts__form_html_slim__2419859499811208315_70341230451880
  app/views/posts/new.html.erb:4:in _app_views_posts_new_html_erb___3935161508588949089_70341230567660
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to reconsider the monkey-patch of ActiveSupport::Safebuffer (the file you've got in `config/initializers/output_safty_encoding_patch.rb`).

Altering behavior of a core class is bound to run into issues that are difficult to debug (like this one).

Maybe you could post a question about the problem that led you to the monkey-patch in the first place?